# Understanding summation index shift

Tags: summation, notation

Suppose I have
$$\sum_{k=n_1}^{n_2} a_k$$
if I define $$k=n-k_1$$ I can write $$\sum_{k_1=n-n_1}^{n-n_2} a_{n-k_1}$$
Then to better assure myself that I understood index shift correctly I write the following system:

$$k=n-k_1$$
$$k\geq{n_1}$$
$$k\leq{n_2}$$
It can be resolved to:
$$k=n-k_1$$
$$k_1\leq{n}-{n_1}$$
$$k_1\geq{n}-{n_2}$$

What is confusing for me here is that inequality signs should be inverted(at least how I understand that) since $k_1$ is in range $n-n_1...n-n_2$. So it seems to me that I didn't understand something correctly although index shift is done formally correct here.
Could you please point out my mistake?

Comment: I haven't read the question carefully. That said, try writing these expressions without the $\Sigma$s for some particular values of $n_1$ and $n_2$. (In general I prefer expressions with ellipses rather than formal manipulations to get an index shift.)

Comment: Inverting comes from your desire to write new limits as **subtracted**  from some given $n$ (formally from "$-$" before $k_1$), i.e 
$$n_1\leqslant n_2 \Rightarrow n-n_2 \leqslant n-n_1$$
So, no mistake, $k_1$ is in range $[n-n_2,n-n_1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $n_{1}\leq n_{2}$ it holds that $n-n_{2}\leq n-n_{1}$ so the correct range for $k_1$ is
$$n-n_{2}\leq k_{1} \leq n -n_{1}.$$
However, what you have written in the sum is still correct because it preserves the *order* in which the terms are summed up. Since $n-k_{1}$ is *smaller* for larger values of $k_{1}$, it follows that,  as we go from the larger $n-n_{1}$ to the smaller $n-n_{2}$ we are in fact increasing the index of $a$ at each term.